# Bootstrap Navbar tab loses focus on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with 2 tabs

```
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li><a href="#taba">Tab A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabb">Tab B</a></li>

              </ul>
           </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Initially on page load, the text of tab (say Tab A) is white in color. When I hover over or click Tab A, its color changes to green which is fine. But when i click somewhere else on the same page, the color of Tab A changes back to white. This confuses the user which tab is in focus.

Is there any way bootstrap allows the text of tab A to remain green no matter where i click on the page unless I click on tab b?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the element's class to "active"

change:

```
<li><a href="#taba">Tab A</a></li>
```

to:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#taba">Tab A</a></li>
```

Comment: But why should I hard code it? If the user clicks on Tab B, what process will change Tab B's li class active?

Comment: The bootstrap.js deals with changing the active class but you have to manually add the class to the initial tab though.